# Creating custom altcoin

Tags: altcoin-development

Is there any guides on how to:

1) Technically create my own cryptocurrency;
2) Publish it on the world crypto-exchanges;
3) Increase price per coin;

Is this company legit: https://dev.cryptolife.net/order/custom-altcoin/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are guides available,you can pay exchanges to add your coin in,you can't increase the price per coin,the price goes up or down based on the demand,if a coin has unique features it's more easy to gain value from a coin created by a company for their client because the client pay for that to in order to have their own altcoin there is little chance of attracting users,users are interested to invest in new things with unique features,with a strong development team that have plans to continue the development of their coin and implement new features..

Comment: Yobit provides a Rise only market feature.